# constructor in controller class - Laravel

Tags: laravel, oop, constructor

I have a question in Laravel that might seem silly

I know that in OOP if we create new object , the first thing happened is calling a constructor method

what about using constructor in Controller class in laravel ,

I found many project using constructor in controller but I didn't see any code

that's create object of a controller

what benefits we get if we defined a constructor in controller , and why we need to do that  ?

also when we need to define a constructor in controller ?

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually use constructors in Laravel controllers for these reasons:

1. **Calling middleware**

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
```

2. **Calling authorization functions** (authorize , authorizeResource etc.).

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(User::class);
    }
```

3. **Initializing variables** so we can use them in the methods defined in said controller.

```
    private $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->foo = 'bar';
    }

    public function getFoo()
    {
        return $this->foo; //returns string 'bar'
    }
```

Comment: 1) if we using something like this   parent::__construct() what really happen ?
2) if I have this code for example  $this->middleware('auth') , where does  middleware method come from ?
3) any suggestion resource for dependency injection ?

Comment: 1- ***parent::__construct()*** it simply calls the parent's constructor which we inherit from it . 2- ***middleware auth*** is a native middleware in laravel , you can find all native middlewares in ***app\Http\Kernel.php*** . you can also define your own middleware and use it in the same way .
3- dependency injection is a general topic , you can see this :

https://www.getopensocial.com/blog/open-source-technology/dependency-injection-php

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: yes I understand but my question is do we inherit middleware method  from another class or what ?

Comment: Personally I'd never make a new instance of a controller and pass in a param, imo if you're doing `new BlahController($passing_a_variable_or_instance)` then something has gone wrong

Comment: @Matrix you should read the comments inside app\Http\Kernel.php, they explain why how and where each middleware class is used. See also: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware

Comment: Actually yes , All these methods are inherited from app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php which all laravel controllers inherit him by default , Take a look at it and you will understand everything